# I am happy now after I heard the news. - mixing tenses - is this correct?

Tags: tense, conjunctions

If I heard the news in the past and the state of being happy is in the present, can I write it like Example 1 or Example 2?

**Example 1**

> I am happy now after hearing the news.

**Example 2**

> I am happy now after I heard the news.

Are they correct English?

Do they mean the same thing?

If I heard the news in the past and the intention to help your friend is also in the future, can I write it like Example 3 or Example 4?

**Example 3**

> I will help my friend after I heard what happened to him.

**Example 4**

> I will help my friend after hearing what happened to him.

Are they correct English?

Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: I think #1 is clumsy, and #2 is non-idiomatic (it's easier to assess them if we discard syntactically / semantically irrelevant ***now***). Much the same applies to #3 and #4, except you've reversed the constructions for that pair. But I can't explain why #3 and #4 *both* seem to become perfectly acceptable if we switch from initial ***I will help...*** to ***I am helping...***

Comment: Far more idiomatic: _I am happy now that I have heard the news_.

Comment: For some reason #3 and #4 seem better to me if ***I will help...*** is replaced by ***I am going to help...*** This preserves the future tense.

Comment: You are not mixing tenses. hearing is a gerund and I heard is a simple past verb.

Answer (score 0):

Your example 1 is a little clunky but totally acceptable. Your example 2 is close to the most natural way of saying this, which would be,

> I'm happy now that I've heard the news.

or

> I'm happy now that I heard the news.

My experience is that the first of these is much more common, but that may be dialectal.

Your example 3 is incorrect - the I will / after construction implies that the thing described in the after clause (I heard what happened to him) has not occured yet, so this example states that both the help and the hearing are in the future. Your example 4 has the same problem - the position of the 'after' after the main clause, not set off by commas, indicates it is an essential part of the sentence. What you're looking for is 'after hearing what happened to him' as a supporting clause, which is set off by commas. In this case, it is most natural to place it at the start of the sentence:

> After hearing what happened to him, I will help my friend.

or

> After I heard what happened to him, I will help my friend.

A minor issue of tone also is worth mentioning; the "I will" construction feels a little stiff for this context; "I'll" or "I'm going to" might fit better in the context.

Comment: "I am happy after hearing the news" is clunky??

Comment: @Lambie yes, I'd say. You're welcome to give an answer if you disagree.